# Using Openssl To Read Multiple Certificates

Tags: linux, shell, openssl

I want to use the following command:

```
openssl x509 -noout -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert1.pem -enddate  
openssl x509 -noout -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert2.pem -enddate  
openssl x509 -noout -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/certN.pem -enddate
```

Is there a way to read all the certificates using wild cards? e.g,

```
openssl x509 -noout -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/*.pem -enddate
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have managed to do it using an array of file names a traversing it with for loop. If there is a better work around this please share. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a shell scriptlet:

```
#! /bin/sh

for file in /etc/pki/tls/certs/*.pem; do
   echo -n "$file: "
   openssl x509 -noout -in "$file" -enddate
done
```

put this in a file, say `certexpires.sh` then you can run it with:

```
sh certexpires.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer for your case is this command:

```
ls /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert*.pem | xargs -L1 openssl x509 -noout -enddate -in
```

**Explanation**

In the first step, I make the list of my certificates that I want to parse. For example in my case it could be like this:

```
[root@vpsfree certs]# ls -1 */*.crt
ewsport.org/ewsport.org.crt
hxpro.cz/hxpro.crt
jaguars.cz/jaguars.crt
koudelka.photography/koudelka.photography.crt
unicycle-hockey.cz/unicycle-hockey.cz.crt
unipragga.cz/unipragga.cz.crt
```

Next step, I want to get expiration date from each of them.

```
[root@vpsfree certs]# openssl x509 -noout -enddate -in hxpro.cz/hxpro.crt
notAfter=Apr 24 11:29:21 2017 GMT
```

Now I can send output from my first command to second using xargs.

```
[root@vpsfree certs]# ls -1 */*.crt | xargs -L1 openssl x509 -noout -enddate -in
notAfter=Mar 31 15:08:20 2017 GMT
notAfter=Apr 24 11:29:21 2017 GMT
notAfter=Mar 23 21:23:42 2017 GMT
notAfter=Apr 24 11:50:32 2017 GMT
notAfter=Dec 11 16:32:41 2016 GMT
notAfter=Mar 20 19:44:17 2017 GMT
```

I used option -L1, because openssl command needs only one -in file as input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please provide some explanation about why the command you've posted solves the OP's problem - and why it may be better than the answers already provided?

Comment: Yeah but...why? What does `| xargs` do? Or `-L1`?

Comment: xargs executes command openssl with parameter from standard input, this parameter is name of the file in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Alias for my terminal which runs this on whole files in folder (you can adjust it to run only on pem extension but this is my adaptation)

```
alias ssl-opemu='_(){ for i in *; do openssl x509 -in $i -noout -text; done; }; _'
```

I am almost sure I have inherited this from a previous thread so all rights to their original owners. :)